# Set Current Carousel Page on the startup. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I have a problem with CarouselPage. When initializing, I assign CarouselPage.ItemSource = ....
At  start i need to show second page, not first.

**My code:**

```
Weeks = new ObservableCollection<Week>
                {
                    new Week {Days = GetDays(currentMonday.AddDays(-7)), ItemTappedCommand = JobTappedCommand},
                    new Week {Days = GetDays(currentMonday), ItemTappedCommand = JobTappedCommand},
                    new Week {Days = GetDays(currentMonday.AddDays(7)), ItemTappedCommand = JobTappedCommand},
                };

                CurrentDate = Weeks[1].DateOfFirstDayOfWeek;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (but I have not test) you can use something like

```
this.CurrentPage = this.Children[1];
```

Comment: `private void CarouselAllJobsWeekPage_OnPagesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   CurrentPage = this.Children[1];
  }
`
Th. I thought this would not work, since I assign the ItemSsource

Answer (score 0):

I make this:

```
private bool _isInitialized;

private void CarouselAllJobsWeekPage_OnPagesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isInitialized
                && Children.Count > 2)
            {
                CurrentPage = this.Children[1];
                _isInitialized = true;
            }
        }
```